# unexpected 2nd argument to function in mustache javascript templating

Tags: javascript, html, templates, mustache

I notice that when using lambdas:

```
{
  "name": "Willy",
  "wrapped": function() {
    return function(text) {
      return "<b>" + render(text) + "</b>"
    }
  }
}
```

a second argument (in addition to `text`) is passed in. This second argument is a function:

```
function (template) {
    return render(template, scope);
}
```

which returns html, given a template (with the inital input json object).

so, if I were to have the lambda as follows:

```
"wrapped": function() {
  return function(text, func) {
    ....
}
```

one would expect   `func("<div>{{name}}</div>")` to return html representing a div with the content being filled in with whatever was in the 'name' property of the json data object.

HOWEVER, `func("{{.}}")` does NOT work.
I would expect the object representing the initial input object.

Instead I get the STRING `"[object Object]"`. When I try to use `JSON.parse` it gives me an 'Unexpected token o' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying to parse as JSON isn't actually JSON. It's just a JavaScript object literal. So when you try to put `{{.}}` into your template, you are rightly getting `[object Object]` because that is the string representation of the object.

Comment: Is there any way I can access the object from within the lambda function then?

Comment: Your example is a little hard to follow, but it seems that rendering it as part of a mustache template is the wrong thing to do. What are you trying to do with it in your mustache template?

Comment: I am using the template to generate html (e.g. a table) code or my site using an an array of objects. I would like to assign each object to each row element of the table using the Jquery .data() method.

Comment: Then shouldn't you use {{#key-for-object}} stuff {{/key-for-object}}? I'm not sure you can pass an object into a mustache template, and still use it as an object, other than with a block statement.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I will end up using a key like you suggested. Thank you.